# Onkeydown event not working when focused on Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How can I get this code to execute even when the focused on the iframe?

```
<Script>
  function check(){ alert("test"); }
</script>

<body onkeydown="check()";>
  Onkeydown event only works when focus is not on iframe...<br>
<iframe src="about:blank" frameborder=1;> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iframe is on a different domain than the hosting site you are out of luck. If not and you don't have control over it, you are out of luck. Else you could modify the iframe page to listen for the `onkeydown` event and invoke a parent javascript function:

```
window.parent.check();
```

Comment: would I be able to place the iframe inside a div / table and get the div / table to listen for the onkeydown event?

Answer (score 0):

The iframe represents a different document and DOM events (e.g. key events) only bubble up within the same document. You will have to attach an additional key down listener to the iframe document.